# Why is a string passed from JavaScript to Wasm always empty in section 4.2 of the Rust/Wasm beginner book?

Tags: rust, webassembly

I'm trying to follow the [Rust WebAssembly book](https://rustwasm.github.io/docs/book/game-of-life/hello-world.html) and I'm stuck at the exercise in section 4.2. I changed everything as described in the answer, but the given `&str` (name) in the `greet` function is always empty.

Here is my version of the `greet` function with debugging

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn greet(name: &str) {
    if name.len() == 0 {
        alert("NOT WORKING!");
    } else {
        alert(&format!("Hello, {}!", name));
    }
}
```

And the **www/index.js** file:

```js
import * as wasm from "wasm-game-of-life";

wasm.greet("213");
```

Here is the generated function in **pkg/wasm_game_of_life.js**

```js
/**
* @param {string} name
* @returns {void}
*/
export function greet(name) {
    const ptr0 = passStringToWasm(name);
    const len0 = WASM_VECTOR_LEN;
    try {
        return wasm.greet(ptr0, len0);

    } finally {
        wasm.__wbindgen_free(ptr0, len0 * 1);

    }

}
```

I get an alert popup with the text `NOT WORKING!`, but I expect `Hello, 213`! Why is my string empty? Is the book out of date or something? I deleted everything and started from scratch without luck...

I'm following the book, these are my first hours with WebAssembly.

Comment: Did you properly link the local npm module? You need to use `npm link` in the `pkg` directory and `npm link wasm-game-of-life` in the `www` directory?

Comment: I followed the instructions just now (for the first time) and it worked for me. I'm using the latest Rust 1.34 so I don't think the book is out of date.

Comment: @PeterHall I think I linked everything properly, because `alert("NOT WORKING!");` is executed. I'll uninstall everything again and start from scratch. I'll also test this in my macOS at the moment I'm working on Ubuntu 18.04. I'm also working with the latest rust version. Good to know that this is working in general so there is something spooky with my environment.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's probably late, but I ran into the same issue today and it's just like this. So, for anybody who hit this, here is the answer:

When you import `import * as wasm from "wasm-game-of-life";`, in `wasm` variable you have the module exported from the rust library. It contains `greet` method, but it's not one that is defined in the JS file, it's a C function which accepts two arguments, pointer to the string and it's length.

When you call `wasm.greet()` with a string param, you pass it to the C function, not to the JS function `greet` - that's why function call works but no string actually passed.

In order to call JS `greet` wrapper you have to import it explicitly (substitute with your js file paths):

```
import { default as wasm, greet } from "wasm-game-of-life"

wasm().then((module) => {
  module.greet("Test");  // this won't work, it's C/rust greet function
  console.log(module);
  greet("Test");  // this should work! it's js wrapper around C function
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to `link` the package, which is not stated in the original tutorial:

in `wasm-game-of-life/pkg` run

```sh
npm link  #or yarn link
```

then in `wasm-game-of-life/www` run

```sh
npm link wasm-game-of-life  #or yarn link wasm-game-of-life
```

reference: https://github.com/rustwasm/book/issues/144